# setStyle backgroundImage in Flex actionscript does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, canvas, adobe

I am dynamically creating a canvas, and I need a background image within the canvas. The canvas is created as it accepts drag drop but the background image does not show up.

The trigger for the canvas is:

```
buttonNew.addEventListener("click",addCanvas);
```

The canvas code is:

```
private function addCanvas(oEvent:Event):void
            {
                caNew = new Canvas();
                caNew.id = "cart"
                caNew.name = "Shopping Cart";
                caNew.x = 100;
                caNew.y = 450;
                caNew.width = 200;                          
                caNew.height = 146;             
                caNew.setStyle("backgroundImage",cart_icon); 
                //caNew.setStyle("backgroundColor","#98AEEF");
                this.addChild(caNew);
                caNew.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_ENTER, dragAcceptShop);
                caNew.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_DROP, dragDropShop);

                laNew = new Label();
                laNew.id = "contain"
                laNew.text = "Shopping Cart";
                laNew.x = 100;
                laNew.y = 450;
                laNew.width = 120;                          
                laNew.height = 50;
                this.addChild(laNew);

            }
```

What am I doing wrong? As if I use backgroundImage it works fine and only the colour works.

Comment: Where do you define cart_icon?

Comment: [Embed("assets/Cart.png")]
   [Bindable]
   private var cart_icon:Class;

Comment: in the code even if I try to add the complete source within quotes "assets/Cart.png" still it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify which version of the Flex SDK you were using, but backgroundImage is not an available style in the Spark theme.  Spark is the default theme for Flex 4 (and later) projects.  [Check out all available sytles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/Canvas.html#styleSummary).

One option is to add an Image component as the first child on the canvas.

Comment: I am using Flex 4.5 and will try out adding the image component as a child in canvas. Would be so much easier if they allowed backgroundImage...